# How to change all css directory after upgrading to HTTPS

Tags: css, https

Out website is just upgraded to HTTPS site but our css files can't be loaded so I found the way to make it accessible by changing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('/assets/css/contact/contact.css') }}">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('//oursite.com/assets/css/contact/contact.css') }}">
```

which works well. 
But my problem now is I have many stylesheets and js accessed by other files and might take time for me to change them manually. Is there a way to make them accessible by changing one file or what file should I change to make my css accessible by other pages?

Comment: `'/assets/css/` is an url that doe not contain the protocol, so the protocol is determined based on the url of the html page it is loaded in. So it seems that `{{ url( ) }}` does something wrong. So the problem is either the library you use or the settings for that library.

Comment: @t.niese But in my local file it is working well in every pages.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not an expert but i think if you just use relative paths like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/contact/contact.css">
```

it would solve your problems

Comment: Thanks but I'm using blade php :)